# How can I get this css rule working?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just wrote a bootstrap column page but one of my classes does not work:

```
.serviceDetails {

  .height {
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }

  p.text , span.text {
    font-size:11px;
  }

  .icon {
    border:11px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

This is my html:

```
    <section class="serviceDetails">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="col-md-2 hidden-xs icon">
                     <i class="fa fa-bandcamp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
....
```

For some reason the .icon class does not work? More info here:[codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/MbaqLz)

Comment: It's because it's nested inside of  `.serviceDetails {}`.

Comment: @DanielD sorry I forgot something in the css.

Comment: Are you using a css preprocesser like Less or Sass and compiling to css? If not, then it won't work. Css doesn't let you nest rules like that.

Comment: The codepen had SCSS style formatting instead of CSS formatting.  You also forgot to add the classes to the icons.  I removed `.serviceDetails{}` and added `icon` to the `div`s

Comment: What are you using as a css preprocesser?

Comment: I am using sass

Comment: Correction it is a scss file which contains the css above. Btw I tried to turn on the scss processor in codepen but icon class still not working?

Comment: Oh ok. I checked the code pen now and it seems to be working for me. As @ms_nitrogen pointed out, not all your divs have the icon class.

Comment: Your **scss** from above must be *compiled* into proper **css**.  In your pen you can set the pre-processor to **scss** with your current code and it works as you expect.  You can also then view the **compiled css** to see how **sass** munges your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your css outside of the nesting does what you need,

```
 .icon {
    border: solid pink 11px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dOYgaV

edit: added color and fill to border, also changed preprocessor settings on codepen.

```
.serviceDetails {

  .height {
    line-height: 12px;
    margin-top: 8px;
  }

  p.text , span.text {
    font-size:11px;
  }

 .icon {
    border: solid pink 11px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }

}
```

Precompiling the sass written above would also fix the problems, http://www.sassmeister.com/ - online compiler 
http://sass-lang.com/ - sass documentation

This is due to the fact that normal css doesn't allow you to nest class rules inside of classes where as sass does support nesting and also a lot of other cool features.

Comment: I just tried it and there is no border on the icon?

Comment: You've added a dimension to fill but no color or type in the css :-)

Comment: @JonSG True, I was just answering "how do I make this work" :-) updating answer.

Comment: I would like to keep it inside the servicedetails class?

Comment: Then you'll need to compile your code using a precompiler for scss, Some environments support it automatically compiling to a normal css file. all of the documentation for this can be found here http://sass-lang.com/

Comment: Alternatively you can use http://www.sassmeister.com/ if you want to try an online compiler by pasting your scss in there :-)

Comment: Yeah you can I've turned it on in the code pen I used above :-D

Comment: Settings > css > css preprocessor > scss if your trying to find it